# Get Resource based on currently authenticated user

Tags: servicestack

If I have an operation using ServiceStack such as GetOrders:

```
[Route("/orders")]
public class GetOrders : IReturn<List<Order>> { }
```

I then use this in a service:

```
[Authenticate]
public class OrdersService : Service
{
    public object Get(GetOrders request)
    {
        var dbOrders = Db.Select<Order>().ToList();
        // What I want is to only get orders of the user making the request
        // var dbOrders = Db.Select<Order>().Where(x=>x.UserId == ??).ToList();
        return dbOrders;
    }   
}
```

Assuming my `Order` entity has a property called `UserId`, how do I get access to the currently logged in user where I can then map to the `UserId` and select only those orders from my database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get access to your typed UserSession via the `SessionAs<T>` method, e.g:

```
[Authenticate]
public class OrdersService : Service
{
    public object Get(GetOrders request)
    {
        var userSession = base.SessionAs<AuthUserSession>();
        var userId = int.Parse(userSession.UserAuthId);
        var dbOrders = Db.Select<Order>(x => x.UserId == userId);
        return dbOrders;
    }   
}
```